# INSERT INTO dependent on IF Statment

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery, sql-insert

I have a Stored Procedure on BigQuery using 1 variable as input

`` Call `project.dataset.sp_x`(load_business int64) ``

This stored procedure has a statment to insert values into a table only if the load_business variable is equal to 1.

Example:

```
IF load_business = 1 THEN (
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.my_table`

Select *
FROM `project.dataset.business_table`
)

END IF;
```

However, it appears the following error **Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword INSERT**

Therefore, which is the best approach to have this statment dependent on a IF.

Note: Using this variable in the **WHERE** clause is not a good approach since the query will run, and therefore bytes will be processed.

Comment: Consult the [manual](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if) for the IF syntax

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move your conditional into the WHERE clause?   The only expectation there is that it's going to produce a result that can be evaluated.   It doesn't need to be a clause based on a column in your table.

```
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.my_table`
Select 
   *
FROM 
    `project.dataset.business_table`
-- If load_business is not 1, nothing will get inserted.
WHERE load_business = 1
```

As an aside, prefer using explicit columns rather than a SELECT * for your INSERTs.   The way you've implemented this is brittle and will break if the DDL on either table changes.